# Simple Jquery function fails in Safari, Chrome and IE

Tags: jquery, function

Here is my simple function

```
$('#save_button').click(function() {
      $(this).attr('disabled',true).val('Saving');

      $('#new_record_form').ajaxForm({
        url: '/',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSubmit: function(){ alert('Boo!'); },
        success: function(){ alert('Hello!'); }
      });
 });
```

This works fine in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer, Chrome or Safari.

Commenting out this line `$(this).attr('disabled',true).val('Saving');` seems to make things work.

Any reasons for this occuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a [html input](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_DISABLED.html) is 'disabled', its not supposed to be able to send input.
Try changing the property to 'readonly' instead.

Answer (score 1):

I usually write `$(accessor).attr("disabled", "disabled");` which results in HTML that looks like `<... disabled="disabled" .../>` being produced. I didn't know that you could use your syntax. Can you try this, and see if it works?

To remove the attribute, I use `$(accessor).removeAttr("disabled");`.

Comment: `true` is the more appropriate value. jQuery's `attr()` changes JavaScript/DOM properties, not HTML attributes (much though jQuery tries to paper over the differences). `disabled` is a boolean property. Setting it to `"disabled"` also works because non-empty strings coerce to `true` in a boolean context.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you cannot modify a control disabled...

but maybe doing this should solve the problem:

```
$('#save_button').click(function() {
      $(this).val('Saving');
      $(this).attr('disabled',true);

      $('#new_record_form').ajaxForm({
        url: '/',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSubmit: function(){ alert('Boo!'); },
        success: function(){ alert('Hello!'); }
      });
});
```